# Tuleap - Users dashboard widget Removal

Tags: widget, artifacts, tuleap

I want to set a customized personal dashboard to my project members. Tuleap by default provides some 7-8 widgets in personal dashboard. I need to remove all these widgets and set:

1. my projects
2. my artifacts(v5)

for all the users, so that when a new project member logs in he'll be seeing only those two widgets.

Could you share the path and file name, where the coding has to be done?